# How to retrieve a value from local storage and set it in an dynamic HTML table input field?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-tables

I have a dynamic html table where a row is added. I need to insert a localstorage value into the input textbox field of the table row

I have tried with jquery etc but because of the "' + count+'" and cannot add a value when i append the row below existing table

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var final_total_amt = $('#final_total_amt').text();
        var count = 1;
var descriptionr1 = localStorage.getItem("descriptionr");
document.getElementById("itemName_'+count+'").value = descriptionr1;

       $(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function(){
         count++;
          $('#total_item').val(count);
          var html_code = '';
          html_code += '<tr id="row_id_'+count+'">';
          html_code += '<td ><span id="sr_no">'+count+'</span></td>';  
          html_code += '<td><input type="text" data-type="description" autocomplete="off"  data-index="9" onfocus="this.select();"   tabindex="0" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_'+count+'" value="" onfocus="this.select();"  class=" form-control input-sm autocomplete_txtc itemName1" /></td>';
```

The variable value does not populate to the new row created in the table, and the "field" stays blank. I assume it has to do with the '+count+' attached to id="itemName_'+count+'"
Please be so kind to advise

Comment: change the line to this `document.getElementById("itemName_"+count).value = descriptionr1`

Comment: Thx Roy, the "("itemName_"+count).value   change works great